# ZendFramework 2 - How to make all the actions available with one router rule? Its only allowing action index

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-route, zend-router

How to allow all sub actions inside that controller with one router rule? For example this follow:

```
visit: site/login                - works only
       site/login/forgetpassword - does not work
       site/login/remmeberme     - does not work
```

Example:

```
$router = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('router');
$route = Http\Literal::factory(array(
  'route' => '/login',
  'defaults' => array(
    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Login',
    'action' => 'index'
  ),
));
$router->addRoute('login', $route, null);
```

**Follow up:**

How can i make it so that /login and /login/anything works?

```
$route = Http\Segment::factory(array(
  'route' => '/login[/:action]',
  'defaults' => array(
    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Login',
    'action' => 'index'
  ),
));
$router->addRoute('login', $route, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellent [QuickStart Tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html) available within the official Documentation. Set up your route like the following to be allowed multiple actions and an ID Parameter. Fur further information please take a look at the documentation.

You may also be interested in [DASPRiDs presentation](http://stuff.dasprids.de/slides/zendcon2012/introducing-the-new-zend-framework-2-router/presentation.html#1) from ZendCon2012

```
 'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: module.config.php: you are using this right? I am not looking for that, i am using in Module.php bootstrap.

Comment: module.config.php: routing concept is time consuming, because the largest array it become. it kills more time to debug, but the Module.php is debug friendly method. Therefore, i have selected the option doing manual routing from Bootstrap but ignoring routing from module.config.php.

Comment: Totally up to you, but it doesn't really change anything :) The array-options are those you have to use for your manual call, too. Instead of using a `Http\Literal` simply use `Http\Segment`. Personally i'm using Literal routes only from module.config.php and the speed disadvantage is within very little ms scope so i don't really bother at all ;)